# Sorting list by most frequent element first - Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to sort a list which takes an ordinary list for example:

```
List("5", "3", "3", "6", "3", "5")
```

And sorts it by the highest element first and turns it into something like this:

```
List("3", "5", "6")
```

I have tried doing something along the lines of

```
val key = list.groupBy(indentity).mapValues(_.size)
val newList = key.KeySet.toList
```

But this doesn't end up sorting the list in order (I think because KeySet sorts it randomly first, not entirely sure though). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So sort based on the occurrences?

Compute the occurrences:

```scala
val occ = 
  List("5", "3", "3", "6", "3", "5")
    .groupBy(identity)
    .mapValues(_.size)
//Map(5 -> 2, 6 -> 1, 3 -> 3)
```

and sort based on the `occ`:

```scala
occ
  .toList
  .sortBy { case (value, occ) => -occ }
  .map(_._1)
//List(3, 5, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked just as intended!

Answer (score 1):

You can sort map elements before producing the list:

```
val list  = List("5", "3", "3", "6", "3", "5")
val key = list.groupBy(identity)
  .view
  .mapValues(_.size)
  .toSeq
  .sortBy(_._2)(Ordering.Int.reverse)
  .map(_._1)
  .toList
```